# Registration Wizard

Tags: 7, users

I 'm looking for help creating a registration wizard.

Currently I am using the [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) and [Multistep](https://www.drupal.org/project/multistep) modules (which allows me to create some sort of wizard on the registration page).

But my problem is that the Register form (let's say "Step 1 of 4") needs to contain fields from both `user_register_form` and the `Profile2` form.

E.g.:

```
"Step 1 of 4"

First Name -> Profile2 field

Last Name  -> Profile2 field  

Email      -> Account field

Job        -> Profile2 field
```

Any ideas of how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Multi-Step Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/step) module instead. It allows to create multi-step (wizard) user account registration forms. Each step of the wizard can be configured to, optionally, expose one ore more Profile2 types.

I think both the fields from Profile2 and User Register can be used in this case.